# Why does c(rbind(letters, LETTERS)) return a vector of an alternating sequence of the lowercase and uppercase alphabet in R?

Tags: r, rbind

R noob here

I was just wondering why running `c(rbind(letters, LETTERS))` gives an output of an alternating sequence:

```
[1] "a" "A" "b" "B" "c" "C" "d" "D" "e" "E" "f" "F" "g" "G" "h" "H" "i"
[18] "I" "j" "J" "k" "K" "l" "L" "m" "M" "n" "N" "o" "O" "p" "P" "q" "Q"
[35] "r" "R" "s" "S" "t" "T" "u" "U" "v" "V" "w" "W" "x" "X" "y" "Y" "z"
[52] "Z"
```

instead of printing the entire lowercase letters vector first, and then the entire uppercase letters vector. What is it about calling c() on a data frame that gives this result? Does this have to do something with the indices of the data frame rows? Thank you!

Comment: Note that you aren't "calling c() on a data frame" here, as the result of the `rbind` is a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a dataframe/matrix is turned to vector by using `unlist` or `c` the default method is to do it column-wise. So in the vector you'll have first all the values of column1, then column 2 and so on.

In your case see the output `rbind(letters, LETTERS)` it is a 2 X 26 matrix.

```
rbind(letters, LETTERS)

#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#letters "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "f"  "g"  "h"  "i"  "j"  
#LETTERS "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J" 

#... 
#...
```

Now when you turn them to vector using `c` it will first have values from column1, then column2 and so on. Column1 has `"a"` and `"A"`, column2 has `"b"` and `"B"` so the final output that you get is vector of alternating sequence.

```
c(rbind(letters, LETTERS))
# [1] "a" "A" "b" "B" "c" "C" "d" "D" "e" "E" "f" "F" "g" "G" "h" "H" "i" "I" "j"
#[20] "J" "k" "K" "l" "L" "m" "M" "n" "N" "o" "O" "p" "P" "q" "Q" "r" "R" "s" "S"
#[39] "t" "T" "u" "U" "v" "V" "w" "W" "x" "X" "y" "Y" "z" "Z"
```

If you want the output to be first all lowercase letter then uppercase check output of `cbind`.

```
cbind(letters, LETTERS)

#    letters LETTERS
# [1,] "a"     "A"    
# [2,] "b"     "B"    
# [3,] "c"     "C"    
# [4,] "d"     "D"    
# [5,] "e"     "E"    
#...
```

and when you convert it to vector you get :

```
c(cbind(letters, LETTERS))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"
#[20] "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L"
#[39] "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z"
```

However, you don't even need `cbind` here you can directly use `c` which gives the same output.

```
c(letters, LETTERS)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `rbind(letters, LETTERS)` generates a matrix with two rows, the top being lowercase letters and the bottom uppercase.  When you call `c()` on that resulting matrix, two things happen.  First, `c()` will coerce the matrix to a vector, which is explained in the [documentation for c()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/c):

> The default method combines its arguments to form a vector. All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value, and all attributes except names are removed.

The rule for coercing a matrix to a 1D vector is to take the column major order, which is what you see in your current output.

To see this in action, consider:

```
temp <- rbind(letters[1:3], LETTERS[1:3])
temp

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "A"  "B"  "C"
```

Then apply `c()`:

```
output <- c(temp)
output

[1] "a" "A" "b" "B" "c" "C"    # column-major order
```

Answer (score 1):

See the problem with a smaller example:

```
rbind(letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e" 
#[2,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"
```

The two vectors were bound by row. And in R matrices are in column-major order. So, when converting the above matrix to a vector, the columns show up in sequence:

```
c(rbind(letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5]))
# [1] "a" "A" "b" "B" "c" "C" "d" "D" "e" "E"
```

If you bind the original vectors by column, the lowercase letters will be first, then the uppercase ones.

```
cbind(letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5])
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "a"  "A" 
#[2,] "b"  "B" 
#[3,] "c"  "C" 
#[4,] "d"  "D" 
#[5,] "e"  "E" 

c(cbind(letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5]))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```